# Detecting gcc warnings from a bash wrapper

Tags: bash, unix, gcc

Writing a bash script that will tell me is the gcc had Errs or warnings
i have this code

```
#!/bin/bash

# execute gcc command
gcc "$2".c -Wall -g -o "$2"> "$1" 2>&1

# grab exit status of gcc
ret=$?

# write appropriate message as per return status value
((ret == 0)) && echo "compile V" || echo "compile X"

# return the exit status of gcc
exit $ret
```

the problem is when it gets warnings its still return 0 and so i get Compile V
But without any luck.. The numbers 6 21 118 are random the rest are consts

edit
i cant use -Werror beause its for school and i must get same output as they want...

Comment: In `gcc`, add the switch `-Werror` so that warnings become errors `:)`.

Comment: but then the output of the file will change? i need it for school..

Comment: But since you're going to fix all the code that generates warnings, it's not a big deal `;)`.

Comment: With `-Werror` your warnings will be treated as errors. That means your file will have them as errors (not warnings). Do you want to be able to recognize warnings separately in your file?

Comment: if only.. its just for training bash scripting, so i must get same output 
maybe it doesnt change the output?

Comment: The only change you'll see is *error:* instead of *warning:* in the output and a line stating so *all warnings being treated as errors*. Is that change not ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to look at whether the file you redirected gcc's output to is empty, that'll tell you whether any warnings were written:

```
gcc "$2".c -Wall -g -o "$2" >"$1" 2>&1; rc=$?
if (( rc > 0 )) || [ -s "$1" ]; then
  echo "compile X"
else
  echo "compile V"
fi
```

This works because `test -s` checks whether a file exists and is non-empty -- so you know that if the file you redirected the output to is non-empty, you had at least one error or failure.

Comment: gcc could also issue *notes* that are not errors/warnings and it will make the file non-empty (and thus wrong output).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, oops -- in a prior version, I hadn't yet noticed that output was going to a file, and was capturing it. Didn't fully excise that.

Comment: @BlueMoon, true. The goal here (per comments) is to match the behavior of another test program that isn't given. I rather suspect that it may have the same misfeature. If that's not the case, then we'd want to run a `grep -q` specific to warnings.

Answer (score 0):

use gcc -Werror option to treat all warnings as errors.